# Android service thread making web request is blocking UI

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface, web, block

First I will explain the current situation.
I've 2 different threads in 2 services(read from usb port service and make web requests service). I'm starting them in onCreate of my activity like:

```
serialServiceIntent = new Intent(NDKSerialActivity.this, SerialService.class);
startService(serialServiceIntent);
webServiceIntent = new Intent(NDKSerialActivity.this, RecordWebService.class);
startService(webServiceIntent);
```

There is nothing wrong with serial service but in RecordWebService when I make a request my gui stops until response comes.

The code is like that:

```
public class RecordWebService extends Service
{
public static final String SERVER_ADDRESS = "http://192.168.1.100:8080/MobilHM/rest";
private static final String TAG = RecordWebService.class.getSimpleName();
private RecordWebThread recordWebThread;

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
{
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    recordWebThread = new RecordWebThread(true);
    recordWebThread.start();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i(TAG, "RecordWebService Destroyed");
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
{
    return null;
}
}
```

and

```
public class RecordWebThread extends Thread
{
private static final String TAG = RecordWebThread.class.getSimpleName();
public boolean always;


public RecordWebThread(boolean always)
{
    this.always = always;
}

@Override
public void run()
{
    PatientRecord patientRecord = new PatientRecord();
    while (always)
    {
        RestClient restClient = new RestClient(RecordWebService.SERVER_ADDRESS + "/hello");
        try
        {
            restClient.execute(RequestMethod.GET);
        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "", e1);
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "Server Response Code:->" + restClient.getResponseCode());
        Log.i(TAG, "Server Response:->" + restClient.getResponse());
        try
        {
            sleep(4 * 1000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "Web service interrupted", e);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Also I've tried to remove sleep part and make the thread to run with timer and timer task like:

```
public void sendRecord()
{
    scanTask = new TimerTask()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            handler.post(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    RestClient restClient = new RestClient(RecordWebService.SERVER_ADDRESS + "/hello");
                    try
                    {
                        restClient.execute(RequestMethod.GET);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e1)
                    {
                        Log.e(TAG, "", e1);
                    }
                    Log.i(TAG, "Server Response Code:->" + restClient.getResponseCode());
                    Log.i(TAG, "Server Response:->" + restClient.getResponse());
                }
            });
        }
    };
    t.schedule(scanTask, 1000, 4000);
}
```

but no luck, my gui hangs when it comes to restClient.execute .

You can find RestClient.java @ http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=1462

How can I make my requests not block my gui thread?

Edit:

```
public void sendRecord()
{
    scanTask = new TimerTask()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            RestClient restClient = new RestClient(RecordWebService.SERVER_ADDRESS + "/hello");
            try
            {
                restClient.execute(RequestMethod.GET);
            }
            catch (Exception e1)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "", e1);
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "Server Response Code:->" + restClient.getResponseCode());
            Log.i(TAG, "Server Response:->" + restClient.getResponse());
        }
    };
    t.schedule(scanTask, 1000, 4000);
}
```

Without handler, I call this in onCreate of my activity but still ui hanging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can use an IntentService which will handle the thread issues for you.

This is an example class:

```
public class MyService extends IntentService {

    public MyService() {
        super("MyService");
    }

    public MyService(String name) {
        super(name);        
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent arg0) {

                //Do what you want
        }
}
```

Then you just call:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MyService.class);
startService(intent);
```

Edit:

To repeat the same thing every 4 seconds you should do something like this:

```
 PendingIntent serviceIntent= PendingIntent.getService(context,
                0, new Intent(context, MyService.class), 0);

   long firstTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
   AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

   long intervalInSec = 4;

   am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, firstTime, intervalInSec*1000, serviceIntent)
```

;

Comment: Thanks sfratini. My work should be repeated with 4 sec interval. Should I call startService with timer or what?

Comment: I edited the answer so you could see an example using AlarmManager

Comment: Thank you a lot. I've just edited the code as you said. Although your solution is valuable, ui is hanging still. I think it may be related more to .execute(request) thing than service, timer etc. I'm looking for async http requests like in actionscript.

Comment: Please post your complete code as it is right now. You dont need to create new threads inside handleIntent. It's all done inside another thread.

Comment: As it seems the blocking part is json. I'm serializing my PatientRecord object to json using flexjson but in android it's killing my app. I'm using Kryo right now and it is perfect. Thank you for your interest. It works both ways including my first implementation and your implementation.

Comment: intentservice will not work if i want my service to running indefinite period of time...in that case what should i do ???

Answer (score 0):

In your code (2d version) happens next: You create thread, and it asks UI thread to do some net interaction. Just exclude `handler.post(...)` while executing request. Later you can use this for simple runnable for updating your UI with results of request.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you can check edit in the post. If not please correct me.